# Why is JSHINT complaining that this is a strict violation?

Tags: javascript, jslint, strict, jshint

> I think  this may be a duplicate of [Strict Violation using this keyword and revealing module pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300937/strict-violation-using-this-keyword-and-revealing-module-pattern)

I have this code:

```
function gotoPage(s){
    if(s<=this.d&&s>0){this.g=s; this.page((s-1)*this.p.size);}
}

function pageChange(event, sorter) {
    var dd = event.currentTarget;
    gotoPage.call(sorter, dd[dd.selectedIndex].value);
}
```

And JSHINT (JSLINT) is complaining.  It says "Strict violation." for the highlighted line:

[image]

Is my use of `Function.call()` and then referencing the instance, somehow inappropriate?

Is this considered to be bad style?

Comment: Does it only say "Strict violation", without any detailed error message?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, I ran the code through JSHint and JSLint and it's not seeming to complain about anything.

Comment: Note that this would be much easier to diagnose if you didn't try to cram it into a ridiculous one-liner :P.

Comment: I've seen this in another question (can't find it right now). It has to do with the use of `this`. I've no idea why JSLint would call it a Strict Violation, but I do know that if you don't define the `this` value of a function, it will be `undefined` in strict mode. Clearly you're defining `this`, so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: You can ignore these *possible strict violations* with `"-W040":true` in the config json, but since json doesn't have comments, you can't tell anyone why it's there.

Comment: or you can add as a comment `/* jshint -W040 */`and when you want to add back this warning put `/* jshint +W040 */`.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

JSHint says "Possible strict violation" because you are using `this` inside something that, as far as it can tell, is not a method.

In non-strict mode, calling `gotoPage(5)` would bind `this` to the global object (`window` in the browser). In strict mode, `this` would be `undefined`, and you would get in trouble.

Presumably, you mean to call this function with a bound `this` context, e.g. `gotoPage.bind(myObj)(5)` or `gotoPage.call(myObj, 5)`. If so, you can ignore JSHint, as you will not generate any errors. But, it is telling you that your code is unclear to anyone reading it, because using `this` inside of something that is not obviously a method is quite confusing. It would be better to simply pass the object as a parameter:

```
function gotoPage(sorter, s) {
    if (s <= sorter.d && s > 0) {
        sorter.g = s;

        sorter.page((s - 1) * sorter.p.size);
    }
}

function pageChange(event, sorter) {
    var dd = event.currentTarget;
    gotoPage(sorter, dd[dd.selectedIndex].value);
}
```

Comment: You're probably right that its complaint is that the function is not defined *explicitly* as a method. Seems silly for JSLint/Hint to call it a *"Strict violation"* though.

Comment: In the web interface and in the latest version, it calls it "_possible_ strict violation."

Comment: Even so, I think they're being a little misleading in the description. Even if `this` does end up being `undefined`, then the *actual* issue isn't just a *strict mode* violation. They would do better to give a warning saying that `this` may be `undefined` when in "strict mode", leading to a `TypeError` (or something).

Comment: @ripper234 indeed, that's why I always use `event.currentTarget` instead of `this`.

Comment: What config directive can I add to `.jshintrc` to disable this check?

Comment: Very nice explanation (+1). "_It would be better to simply pass the object as a parameter_" suggestion really improves code quality.

Comment: @callum "validthis": true

Comment: Use `/* jshint validthis: true */` if you only have a couple and don't want to change for every case.

Comment: If you assign the function to an eventListener callback for example, then you cannot use parameters anyway...

Comment: @Domenic wow, using even.currentTarget really makes the trick ! great :D

Answer (score 94):

I've had this message for a function that did not start with a capital letter.

```
"use strict";

// ---> strict violation
function something() {
    this.test = "";
}


// ---> just fine (note the capital S in Something)
function Something() {
    this.test = "";
}
```

Comment: I would note that jshint is probably assuming, due to convention, that `Something` is a constructor due to the capital S, and so should be called using `new`.  Doing so defines `this` to be a new object based on `Something.prototype'. It's most likely due to that assumption that it doesn't raise the possible strict violation warning.

Comment: I had this error on an AngularJS provider, therefore upper-camel-case method names are expected and I had lower-camel-case. Fixed.

Comment: I had the similar problem, when having a function name only lowercase, renaming using a Capital.

Comment: Don't use capital first letter because it also a constructor, you will face another problem. instead of, you can use: var fnAbc = function(){this.test = ""}

Comment: The capital letter does not change anything about the inner workings of the function. It is just something programmers usually do this way to convey meaning. In other words: this is not a technological problem, but one of communication between homans.

Answer (score 9):

If you declare the function as a variable instead of using the standard function declaration, jshint will not flag this as a strict violation. So you may do the following -

```
var gotoPage = function (s){
    if(s<=this.d&&s>0){this.g=s; this.page((s-1)*this.p.size);}
};


var pageChange = function (event, sorter) {
    var dd = event.currentTarget;
    gotoPage.call(sorter, dd[dd.selectedIndex].value);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to implement a method, you might want to assign to the prototype instead:

```
ExampleClassName.protytpe.gotoPage = function gotoPage(s){
  // code using this
};
```

JSHint won't warn when the function is being assigned.

Comment: Still not good enough. `ClassName.prototype.myMethod = myMethod;`, then defined the method below. You still get an error even though myMethod is correctly bound.