# d3.js on event + jshint possible strict violation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jshint

I have an on `mouseover` event handler bound to a bar chart rect svg objects.

```js
 svg.selectAll('.bar')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .on('mouseover', mouseover)
    .on('mouseout', mouseout)
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d[keyName]); })
    .attr('height', y.rangeBand())
    .attr('width', function(d) { return x(d[valueName]); })
    .attr('val', function(d) { return d[valueName]; });
```

I call the `mouseover` function which gets gets the rect object that the user is hovering over and pulls some values along with setting the fill style. Everything is working as aspected but when I run jshint it warns me about "Possible strict violation" on my use of `this`. Any idea on how to get this lint case to pass with D3?

```js
function mouseover() {
var val = d3.select(this).attr('val');

div.transition()
    .duration(200)
    .style('opacity', 0.9);

div.html(val + ' Servers')
    .style('left', (d3.event.pageX + 20) + 'px')
    .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 20) + 'px');

d3.select(this).style('fill', 'brown');
}
```

Comment: Probably because JShint sees it as a violent as `this` is not used within a method. Remember: JShint is, *hinting*, and it is not always 100% correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is JSHINT complaining that this is a strict violation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688765/why-is-jshint-complaining-that-this-is-a-strict-violation)

Answer (score 1):

Use function expression instead of declaration like

```
var mouseover = function () {
var val = d3.select(this).attr('val');

div.transition()
    .duration(200)
    .style('opacity', 0.9);

div.html(val + ' Servers')
    .style('left', (d3.event.pageX + 20) + 'px')
    .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 20) + 'px');

d3.select(this).style('fill', 'brown');
};
```