# Decorating functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, decorator

Here is a simple decorator pattern which modifies a normal function:

```
function decorator1(f){
   function wrapper(...args){
       pre();
       return f(...args);
       post();
   }
   return wrapper
}
```

Now assume there is an object `obj` and it has a property `prop` in its prototype. I want to modify the object's bound function for some reason.

I can't use this pattern directly to decorate the bound function `obj.prop` because if I pass it as an argument to the `decorator`, it won't get invoked with the correct object in the `wrapper` because JavaScript relies on the **calling** to pass the correct object. So `obj.prop()` is context-aware but `obj.prop` is not. Is there a way to overcome this limitation?

If that is not possible I need to either:

Change the pattern to accept the object and property as 2 different arguments and make it work.

```
function decorator2(o, f){
   function wrapper(...args){
       pre();
       return o.f(...args);
       post();
   }
   return wrapper
}

obj.prop = decorator2(obj, prop);
```

Pass a bound function which for some reason I think is a hard-coding.

```
// This creates a bound function to itself.
obj.prop = obj.prop.bind(obj)
// This modifies it.
obj.prop = decorator1(obj.prop)
```

Which one is preferred? I would go for the former because I think that creating bound functions are not good unless you really need them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `this` in the `wrapper`:

```
function decorate(f) {
    return function wrapper(...args) {
        pre();
        const res = f.apply(this, args); // or f.call(this, ...args)
//                          ^^^^
        post();
        return res; // make post() work
    };
}
```

With this, a plain `obj.prop = decorate(obj.prop);` will work.

Comment: Yes @Bergi, this is another one I tried. Thanks for pointing it out. This one makes it callers responsibility to pass the object preserving the original behavior which is the cleanest thing to do. I got a JS Lint warning saying that  `if a strict mode function is executed using function invocation 'this' will be undefined`. Do I have to worry about that? I thought this is the best approach actually.

Comment: The error code is `w040`. Probably something I can ignore based on the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688765/why-is-jshint-complaining-that-this-is-a-strict-violation?

Comment: Yes, you should ignore that warning. We *want* `this` to be `undefined` when the caller doesn't provide one, because then we don't want to provide one to `f` either.