# Jslint strict violations errors

Tags: javascript, oop, jslint

I was about to try out do some OOP code in js, nothing fancy just wanna see how it works.
I read up on some documentations on the web, but the code gives me error in jslint.
I never used jslint so im not really sure how crucial the error messages are and I hope you guys can help.

```
function mainClass(arg1, arg2) {

"use strict";

this.property1 = arg1;
this.property2 = arg2;

this.printClass = function printClass() {

    return this.property1 + " " + this.property2;

}}
```

thats a simple enough js class but I get some errors and the errors are:

> ln5 Strict violation.      this.property1 = arg1;
>
> ln6 Strict violation.      this.property2 = arg2;
>
> ln8 Strict violation.          this.printClass = function printClass() {
>
> ln12 Expected ';' and instead saw '}'.

So appareantly the errors are that I used this in a global context, as I read on some other posts, but I don't know how im supposed to go about it to get it fixed.

Is this not a correct way of writing a js class?

**UPDATE!**

```
var mainClass = function(arg1, arg2) {
'use strict';

this.property1 = arg1;
this.property2 = arg2;

this.printClass = function printClass() {
    return this.property1 + ' ' + this.property2;
};};
```

I updated the code to the code above, and it works just like the other code, is there any diffrence I should be aware of declaring a class like this and the way above? And this one validate aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, [JSHint](http://jslint.com/) is a bit strict on stuff. But your code is fine, it validates perfectly when you indent it properly. Also, you were forgetting a `;` at the end of one of the function declarations:

```
var foo = function (arg1, arg2) {
    'use strict';

    this.property1 = arg1;
    this.property2 = arg2;

    this.printClass = function printClass() {
        return this.property1 + ' ' + this.property2;
    };
};
```

Or use the [`validthis` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12375408/2612112), which *suppresses warnings about possible strict violations when the code is running in strict mode and you use this in a non-constructor function*.

Comment: Good catch on the ; stupid mistake, but the first 3 errors are still there even with proper indenting.

Comment: @BjörnHjorth I just realized that you were using JSHint not JSLint. This should validate, though you're probably going to get a `'foo' is defined but never used.` error.

Comment: I'm using Adobe Edge Code that has built in JSLint, I dont know what JSHint is.

Comment: I updated the first post with new code and that one works, what is the diffrence between that and the other?

Comment: Both declarations are _almost_ synonymous (read http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-function-declaration-ambiguity/), but with the var "shorthand" version JSHint doesn't throw a warning.

Comment: Thanks for your time you have helped me solve the problem. much appreciated.